# using big files from res/raw

Tags: android

I am trying to develop dictionary application which uses source files from res/raw.
It works when i use a smaller file, but not with a file that I have to use which is cca 5mb.

I decided to split it in parts and to use it this way because it appears that android has some file size limits for assets folder(1mb?).
But it doesnt work this way, it loads something in the program but not all the dictionary files. What seems to be the problem? Am I going in a completely wrong way about this?

```
    private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions1);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        ucitaj(reader);

        InputStream inputStream2 = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions2);
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream2));
        ucitaj(reader2);

        InputStream inputStream3 = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions3);
        BufferedReader reader3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream3));
        ucitaj(reader3);

        InputStream inputStream4 = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions4);
        BufferedReader reader4 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream4));
        ucitaj(reader4);

        InputStream inputStream5 = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions5);
        BufferedReader reader5 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream5));
        ucitaj(reader5);

        InputStream inputStream6 = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions6);
        BufferedReader reader6 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream6));
        ucitaj(reader6);
```

--

```
  private void ucitaj(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, " -- ");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }
```

Comment: "it loads something in the program but not all the dictionary files" what exactly is loaded and what isn't? Can you give us the code for the `ucitaj` method?

Comment: I have added ucitaj method here, but had some problems debugging what exactly has been loaded because it saves data into sqlite database on android and it is a bit harder to properly debug it on computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure - that chunking into several resources is useless, since anyway you're reading in the end all files into RAM/heap, which size is limited. In resembling situation (I need to show in TextView relatively large text) I had overcome situation using special class which was implementing `CharSequence` interface. In fact CharSequence has several abstract methods which can be used for chunking/positioning in big file for necessary fragments, like:

```
abstract char charAt(int index)
abstract CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end)
```

Probably in your situtation it might help.

Comment: RAM size is limited, but this file that I am using is 5MB, I think it is not even nearly exceeding this limits? Btw I am putting this definitions of words from my source file into a sqlite db.